# Phonegap Build - Error - app does not support the compulsory arm64 (64-bit support) architecture

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm using Windows 7 and vs2012 to make a Phonegap application.

I've already uploaded a build successfully to Phonegap Build, however i noticed that the Iphone was picking up and old version of my software which I was keeping in a backup file.

I've removed any traces of the old software and now I'm getting the above error when trying to build for IOS.

```
Error - A plugin in your app does not support the compulsory arm64 (64-bit support) architecture.
```

At first I thought it was some plugins I had that I didn't need, but I've now removed all the plugins I can see and am still getting this error.

This is my config file below;

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.blah.blah" version="1.0.4" VersionCode="104" android-versionCode="2"
      ios-CFBundleVersion="1.0.4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Bleh App</name>
    <description>Bleh Application.</description>
    <author email="Bleh@bleh.com" href="http://phonegap.com">Bleh Limited</author>
    <content src="index.html" />

  <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVesionString">
    <string>1</string>
  </gap:config-file>

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleVersion">
      <string>104</string>
    </gap:config-file>


  <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="CFBundleURLTypes">
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>PackageName</key>
        <string>Bleh App</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>1.0.4</string>
      </dict>

      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleShortVesionString</key>
        <string>107</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </config-file>




  <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="ios" spec="~3.9.1" />
</widget>
```

I have used the Phonegap CLI to remove any plugins attached to the site. There are plugins in the folders, but they aren't doing anything, should they be removed too?

Any help would be appreciated!

*definitely removed all plugins, there was a  tag still around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to delete my app from the Phonegap build website and re-upload it. Hope this solution helps someone.